# When getServletContext.getContextPath() and request.getContextPath() could be different?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, contextpath

I can't figure out a scenario when `getServletContext.getContextPath()` and `request.getContextPath()` would return different Strings.

[HttpServletRequest.getContextpath()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath--) javadoc:

> It is possible that a **servlet container may match a context by more
>   than one context path.** In such cases this method will return the
>   *actual context path* used by the request *and it may differ from the
>   path returned by the ServletContext.getContextPath() method*. The
>   context path returned by ServletContext.getContextPath() should be
>   considered as the prime or preferred context path of the application.

[ServletContext.getContextPath()](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath--) javadoc:

> **It is possible that a servlet container may match a context by more than one context path.** In such cases the
>   HttpServletRequest.getContextPath() will return the *actual context
>   path* used by the request *and it may differ from the path returned by
>   this method*. The context path returned by this method should be
>   considered as the prime or preferred context path of the application.

When my application is within Tomcat's `webapps/ROOT` folder both methods return "" (empty String).

In all other cases, if my app is in myapp.war (put in Tomcat's webapps folder), both methods return "/myapp" as expected.

When I put `my.war` and `mymy.war` into Tomcat's webapps folder, Tomcat sees two distinct web applications, so I cannot model this *"servlet container may match a context by more than one context path"* case.

I cannot call my WARs `my.war` and `my/my.war` because "/" is not allowed in file names both on Windows and Unix.

Answer (score 0):

This is supported because [it's pretty straightforward to have multiple context paths mapped to the same webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721966/how-can-i-map-multiple-contexts-to-the-same-war-file-in-tomcat).

Here some other ways to achieve the same thing:

- [Tomcat: two context paths for one webapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716525/tomcat-two-context-paths-for-one-webapp)
- [adding a global URI prefix for Tomcat web apps](https://serverfault.com/q/380200)